# Is it a good approach to place env file on production server in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, server

This question is more of a general knowledge question about Laravel.
Please suggest me, is it a good approach and safe to place env file on the production server.

I think, env is only for local environment. For production, we should use config folder variables.

Please share your thoughts

Comment: You should use [both](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration), but keep sensitive data out of the config folder pages.

Comment: Sorry, but questions like this, asking for our opinions, are off-topic here.

Comment: I think it goes beyond opinion but should be done for the matter of security and the ability to share code through different environments. Most development projects use some sort of version control, like git. The .env file should be set-up to be ignored by version control, allowing you to keep one version of .env on production with only the credentials of the live environment, while each developer keeps a version of .env that reflects his/her local environment (database name, pw, api keys, etc.)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: Why not put production variable only in the config folder. Afterall laravel application can run without env file.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel docs do suggest using .env for your application environment configuration. You create different configurations for different application stages.
In production make sure to change

```
APP_ENV=local
```

to:

```
APP_ENV=production
```

and:

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```